# Telethon sign_up method consistently returns PhoneCodeInvalidError

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am writing a program that creates Telegram accounts with the [sign_up method](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html?highlight=sign_up#telethon.client.auth.AuthMethods.sign_up) provided by the [telethon library](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon). When I enter the code sent by the program to my phone it returns [PhoneCodeInvalidError](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/auth/sign_up.html#examples) despite the code being valid.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient


async def main():

     phone = '+390000000000'

     await client.connect()

     await client.send_code_request(phone)

     code = input('enter code: ')
     await client.sign_up(phone=phone, code=code, first_name="Anna")


if __name__ == '__main__':
     client = TelegramClient('helohelohelo', 12345, abcdefghi)
     client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I've been looking for a solution everywhere, few people have talked about this problem and almost everything I have read had unclear resolution explanations.

Everything I've read about this issue:
[1](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/478), [2](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/763), [3](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/1386)

Answer (score 2):

Any code sent over Telegram is immediately invalidated. Try putting spaces between each digit of the code.